# No identities were Available

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, app-store-connect

I have created new provisioning profile, certificate, etc. But when i archive my application for publishing to iTunes store it gives me an error that No Identites were available. An administrator must request identities before they can download. When selecting the download identities from dev center it shows my developer account but then comes back to the same screen going in an endless circle. How do i resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you check that your provisioning file that you signed with is a distribution prov?

Comment: Are you asking if the provisioning profile matches the provisioning profile is the same as the one that pulls upon pulling the archive in organizer to use during distribute button select? If so yes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your bundle identifier in your target -> info matches the one on your provision profile in the dev center.

Comment: Yes they both have the same. 'com.soi.Mag742'. Is there a way to refresh the data because it seems as if this is not properly pulling the data. Or refresh my iTunes data. I re-entered the bundle id to match in the info.plist, as well as the general tab to ensure this was correct with no spaces, etc.. I even reinstalled Xcode. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Code Signing Identity in the Code Signing section under the Build Settings for your project. Make sure the identity there for Release matches up to a valid iOS Distribution role (under Preferences-->Accounts-->Apple ID-->View Details).  Also, while there, check that the project's Distribution Provisioning Profile is there.